# Seaborn - polar plot - how to change degrees in the FacetGrid

Tags: python, visualization, data-visualization, seaborn

I am using the [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org) to make a polar plot. here is my code:

```
r = np.linspace(0, 10, num=100)
df = pd.DataFrame({'r': r, 'rs': r})
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['r'], var_name='measure', value_name='theta')
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="measure", hue="measure",
              subplot_kws=dict(projection='polar'), size=4,
              sharex=False, sharey=False, despine=False)

g.map(plt.scatter, "theta", "r")
```

and the output is :
[image]

as you see the degrees are 0,45,90,...
How can I change this interval?

**Edit 1**: thanks to @Julio Daniel Reyes, the degrees problem has been solved but now I have another question: I need a line between points. I don't need dots here. I have checked the `matplotlib` docs and I couldn't find a solution. I tried `linewidths` but didn't worked for me in `.scatter(x,y,linewidths)`

I need something like this:

[image]

**Edit 2** Since I changed my code like this:

```
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.scatter(x=[radians(x) for x in df['degree'].values], 
y=df['value'].values)
```

Replacing the scatter with plot, didn't worked for me!

Regards.

Comment: it should, try with `ax.plot([radians(x) for x in df['degree'].values], df['value'].values)`

Comment: If works for you please accept my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the ticks with radians like this:

```
angle_ticks = np.multiply([0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 1.75, 2.0], np.pi)
g.set(xticks=angle_ticks)
```

Or if you prefer

```
n_ticks = 10
angle_ticks = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, num=n_ticks + 1)[:-1]
g.set(xticks=angle_ticks)
```

Update 1:
To get a line instead of dots you just need to replace `plt.scatter` with `plt.plot` like this:

```
g.map(plt.plot, "theta", "r")
```

Update 2:
For your latest code:

```
ax.plot([radians(x) for x in df['degree'].values], df['value'].values)
```

Comment: tnx, but didn't worked with my new code. (edited in question)  ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True) 
ax.scatter(x=[radians(x) for x in df['degree'].values], y=df['value'].values)